# Подскажите как сделать открытие модального окна bootstrap в определённый промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Есть модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Сейчас мы закрыты<br>
        Режим работы с 10:00 до 22:00
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите как сделать что бы посетителю это окно открывалось один раз при каждом новом заходе на сайт с 22:00 до 10:00?

Answer (score 0):

При посещении пользователем страницы получаете его время:

```
let now = new Date();
```

Переводите время в секунды:

```
const hourse = now.getHours()
const minutes = now.getMinutes()
const seconds = now.getSeconds()

now = hourse * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
```

Проверяете, в какой диапазон входит текущее время:

```
  const minHours = 10 * 3600
  const maxHourse = 22 * 3600
    if (now > minHours && now < maxHourse) {
        now = maxHourse - now
    } else {
      now = 0
    }
```

Затем создаете функцию, которая по истечении времени (расчетов выше), запускает ваш код появления модального окна.

```
function showModal(time) {
       setTimeout(() => {
          //Ваш код
       }, time)
    };
```

Ну и вызываете функцию:

```
showModal(now * 1000);
```

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать как это вставить в HTML?

Comment: А вы подключали js к странице и работали с ним?

Comment: Да, я в index.html добавил это <script type="text/javascript" >

let now = new Date().getHours()

if (now > 10 && now < 22) {
    now = 22 - now
} else {
  now = 0
}

function showModal(time) {
       setTimeout(() => {
          
    //Ваш код
    
       }, time)
    };

showModal(now);

</script> Только в место ваш код, код модального окна

Comment: Перевел часы в миллисекунды, должно работать